# android speech recognition using native code

Tags: android, android-ndk, speech-recognition, native-code

Is there a way to access speech recognition in Android in native code?

From the material that I have referred I understand that Android either provides a Recognizer intent that has to be fired to retrieve the recognition results or use a RecognitionListener. None of these however provide access to the input buffer,that can processed before sending it to google's servers.

Comment: You always have an option to try [CMUSphinx](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/2011/05/building-pocketsphinx-on-android/)

Comment: Thanks for the comment Nikolay. I agree I can use pocketSphinx. But my current project mandates the use of google's voice recognition.

Answer (score 0):

you can use it through java native interface (jni). jni allows to communicate between java to c++ or vice versa. But it a time consuming process, think before u put your hands into it